# How can I make a function work differently for desktops and for mobiles?

Tags: plugins

I'd like this echo function would work differently for desktops/tablets and mobiles, in particular the height of the image should be different (about 600px for desktops, about 300 px for mobiles). Or, alternatively, set the ratio 800/600 for all the screens

```
echo do_shortcode('[meta_gallery_slider arrows="false" show_caption="false" show_title="false" autoplay="false" slider_height="450"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, you need to explicitly set the height of the slider using media queries in CSS. This may or may not work, depending on how the JavaScript for the slider works.

```css
.slider-selector {
    height: 300px;
}

@media ( min-width: 769px ) {
    .slider-selector {
         height: 600px;
    }
}
```